# OOP, MVC - Models and Objects

Tags: database, oop, model-view-controller, design-patterns, codeigniter

I'm building a site with CodeIgniter, and my I have a model called `Blog_model`.

Within `Blog_model`, there are methods to pull a list of posts for a specific topic, for example, `getPopularPosts()`.

`getPopularPosts()` queries the posts table for a list of posts with a `topic_id` matching the one specified and sorts them by popularity.  So, that's one query against the entire table of posts (let's assume this will be very large eventually) to find all posts with `topic_id` *x*.

Then, `foreach` result `as` an individual post id, it creates a new `Post` object.  The `Post` class constructs a post by setting the field `id`.

To return the contents of a `Post`, I assign `$post->getPost();`, which queries the posts table again to return the entire row for the given `id`.

This organization (AFAIK) follows a nice object oriented principle.  But now, for every posts (again, let's assume thousands, millions, whatever...), I have to first query for a list of `id`s and then again to get each post's content.  If I'm returning 30 posts, that means 31 separate queries.

Alternatively, I could break the object oriented pattern and pull `*` for each post in `posts` where `topic_id` = *x*.  Then, I have one query that returns all 30 posts, but now I don't feel so object oriented.

What to do?

Comment: Do you feel it is important to "feel so object oriented?" - If you're worried about performance or something, you could have this run in the back end as complete oo on change and write the results into flat text files. Then you don't even need to run queries for each post, you can just use the id from the initial query to display the results from the cached file. But if you're looking for a comment that chooses one of the options you mentioned, I would go with a joined query. Code igniter, if I am not mistaken, is not strictly oo. Kohana I think is, and they have the ORM to do what you want.

Comment: If it makes a difference, it's CodeIgniter 2.

Comment: There is a lot of information in your question, please give code specific examples of what you are talking about if you want them properly addressed here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason to have that many queries. You're basically just looking for X number of posts that are from a particular topic ID... you should return this as one object and then iterate through the result in PHP because it is significantly faster to do it that way once you get to the point of having millions of rows

You should go about it more like this:

```
class blog_model extends CI_Model {

     function __construct(){
         parent::__construct();
     }

     function getPopularPosts($cat_id){
        /* Using method chaining here since you sound like you
           really want to utilize everything OO CI has to offer */
        $posts = $this->db->select('id, title, post_info')
                  ->where('topic_id', $topic_id)
                  ->get('posts');

        if($posts->num_rows() > 0){
             return $posts;
        }else{
             return FALSE;
        }
     }    
}
```

Then your controller would look like this:

```
class blog extends CI_Controller {

     function __construct() {
         parent::__construct();
     }

     function blog_posts($popular_post_id) {
         $this->load->model('blog_model');
         $posts = $this->blog_model->getPopularPosts($popular_post_id);

         if(!empty($posts){
             foreach($posts as $post){
                 echo $post->id;
                 echo $post->title;
                 echo $post->post_info;
             }
         }else{
             echo 'There are no posts';
         }

     }

 }
```

There is no benefit (and actually a big problem) with generating a ton of queries in the fashion that you currently have it set up, vs generating one object from the query and iterating through each of the rows in the controller and doing whatever you need with the data.

Comment: But in the spirit of OOP (and maybe this means missing the forest for the trees), wouldn't it be more 'correct' to put such logic in the `Post` class? Because maybe I want to get replies for a specific post.  With your method, this puts `getPost()` and `getReplies()` under the same class; whereas, it would seem to me that `getReplies()` should be a method of the `Post` class.

Comment: Yeah i think you're completely missing the boat on what OOP actually means and how to implement it... If you're going to get replies for a single entry, that should be a different function in the blog_posts model and only query for a particular blog post id... if you're going to be getting multiple replies for multiple posts then you're going to be looking to do some mysql JOINs. A simple way to put it is that your goal should be to accomplish what you need using the least number of queries as possible. OOP is just a way of doing things to keep you organized.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that I initially had things set up in the way you describe.  Based on your answer, I've reverted back to this setup.  The overall weight of the code is fairly similar to what it would be with `Post` and `Reply` classes, and even though things aren't as organized as I'd like, it's still very DRY.  Additionally, I can run a single query in place of `(_number-of-posts_) + 1`.